# AS3 - Apply BitmapData addChild to multiple MovieClips

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to add "_myThumb" to 4 container MovieClips. The problem is that it's only working for 1 MovieClip. What do I need to change?

```
var _myThumb:Bitmap;
    var _myThumbData:BitmapData;

    function createThumbs()
    {
        _myThumbData = new BitmapData(photodefault.width,photodefault.height,false,0xffffff);
        _myThumb = new Bitmap(_myThumbData);
        _myThumb.smoothing = true;
        _myThumb.scaleX = _myThumb.scaleY = 0.2;
        // Add to t1-t4 container
        photothumbs.t1.addChild(_myThumb);
        photothumbs.t2.addChild(_myThumb);
        photothumbs.t3.addChild(_myThumb);
        photothumbs.t4.addChild(_myThumb);
    }

    createThumbs();   

    function createThumbnail()
    {
        _myThumbData.draw(photodefault);
    }
```

Thanks.
Uli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create separate Bitmap objects for each thumb, but you can use the same source Bitmapdata for that.  This is an example using a utility function to create the bitmap object:

```
function createThumbs()
{
    _myThumbData = new BitmapData(photodefault.width,photodefault.height,false,0xffffff);
    // Add to t1-t4 container
    photothumbs.t1.addChild(createBitmap(_myThumbData));
    photothumbs.t2.addChild(createBitmap(_myThumbData));
    photothumbs.t3.addChild(createBitmap(_myThumbData));
    photothumbs.t4.addChild(createBitmap(_myThumbData));
}

function createBitmap(bmd:BitmapData):Bitmap
{
    var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
    bitmap.smoothing = true;
    bitmap.scaleX = bitmap.scaleY = 0.2;
    return bitmap;
}
```